# unable to access template reference variable inside *ngIf

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error displayed  in screenshot.
[image]

When I click the search link, I am displaying the search input, I am using keyup event to get values  from input. But getting the error shown in screenshot.
I am using angular 6.

**component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-temp',
  templateUrl: './temp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./temp.component.css']
})
export class TempComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displaySearch = false;
  @ViewChild('searchValue') searchValue: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   searchFunc() {
      if (this.displaySearch === false) {
          this.displaySearch = true;
      } else if (this.displaySearch === true){
          this.displaySearch = false;
   }
```

}

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.searchValue.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        return (event.target).value;
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

> **Html**

```
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="searchFunc()">Search</a>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="displaySearch">
  <input type="text" name="searchValue" #searchValue>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: where is your searchFunc() in ts file?

Comment: it is in component, at the moment I want to read value in component.

Comment: I am trying to read the value using fromEvent() operator.

Comment: but bro you wrote searchFunc() in the a tag write but I can not see searchFunc() in your ts file then how can you change the value of displaySearch.

Comment: bro can you please make this project in stackblitz?

Comment: sorry @pavan while updating code it was overriden , now i have updated again

Comment: @ Pavan Nagadiya , I am using anguar 6, but stackblitz is using angular 8, in which there  is a change in @viewChild implementation, thats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use **`this.searchValue.nativeElement`** in **`ngAfterViewInit()`**.
The reason is when **`TempComponent`** is loading **`searchValue`** input is not in the **`DOM`** as **`displaySearch`** is **`false`** at that time. You should use **`nativeElement`** after **`displaySearch`** becomes **`true`**.
change your code as follows.

```
   searchFunc() {
    this.displaySearch = true;
    setTimeout(() => {

    fromEvent(this.searchValue.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        return (event.target).value;
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });

    },3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's kinda expected.

`ngAfterViewInit` would run right after the view gets initialized. And your `searchValue` template variable comes in view, only after clicking on the Search link. And in the `ngAfterViewInit` method, you're trying to read `nativeElement` on something, which at that moment, would be undefined.

Hence the error.

#### UPDATE:

By reading the data from `@ViewChild` you're making it unnecessarily difficult for yourself.

How about just listening to the `keyup` event on the `input` field using the event binding syntax:

```
<div *ngIf="displaySearch">
    <input 
    type="text" 
    name="searchValue" 
    (keyup)="onKeyUp($event.target.value)" />
</div>
```

And you'll get the value in the `onKeyUp` method.

**NOTE:** The Solution suggested by Vega, is a great solution too. But it won't scale well. Since the `ngAfterViewChecked` method gets called on every change detection cycle. So I won't recommend using that.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-value-from-input-that-is-displayed-conditionally) for your ref.

Comment: How to get the  template refrence  variable value in above case, if the search box is visible I want to read its valuse.

Comment: What exactly is the use case? What are you trying to achieve with this? If you can provide some clarity on that, we'll be able to help you out.

Comment: @ SiddAjmera, this code is demo code ,but  in my real project one block of html get displayed using condition *ngIf, in this html block there is search box with template refrence variable in it . The want to read value of input  through keyup event.